# Impute entire DataFrame (all columns) using Scikit-learn (sklearn) without iterating over columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataframe

I want to impute all of the columns on a pandas DataFrame...the only way I can think of doing this is column by column as shown below...

**Is there an operation where I can impute the entire DataFrame without iterating through the columns?**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Imputer
fill_NaN = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=1)

#Model 1
DF = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,np.nan],[2,np.nan,3],[np.nan,2,5]])
DF.columns = "c1.c2.c3".split(".")
DF.index = "i1.i2.i3".split(".")

#Impute Series
imputed_DF = DF
for col in DF.columns:
    imputed_column = fill_NaN.fit_transform(DF[col]).T
    #Fill in Series on DataFrame
    imputed_DF[col] = imputed_column

#DF
#c1  c2  c3
#i1   0   1 NaN
#i2   2 NaN   3
#i3 NaN   2   5

#imputed_DF
#c1   c2  c3
#i1   0  1.0   4
#i2   2  1.5   3
#i3   1  2.0   5
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want the `mean` or `median` you could do something like:

```
fill_NaN = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=1)
imputed_DF = pd.DataFrame(fill_NaN.fit_transform(DF))
imputed_DF.columns = DF.columns
imputed_DF.index = DF.index
```

If you want to fill them with 0s or something you could always just do:

```
DF[DF.isnull()] = 0
```

Comment: I'd found so many bad examples and this was the first one to make sense to me.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't gotten any good feedback from one of my answers so I really appreciate it.

Comment: +1 for including the steps to restore DataFrame type with original column names and index, after raw numpy array comes out of any sklearn Imputer

Answer (score 7):

Unless you specifically need to use the sklearn `Imputer` for some reason, it seems to me  that a simpler option would be to just do:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: That's probably what I would do now.  Maybe something along the lines of `df[df.isnull()] = x`.  I don't think I would actually `impute` anything in a real world dataset tho.

Answer (score 1):

df.mean() will return NA if any of the columns contains NA, therefore making df.fillna() not function as expected. A proper way would be using np.nanmean()